# c# tpl, problems with continuewith "Calling thread cannot access object because different thread owns it"

Tags: visual-studio-2010, task-parallel-library

I'm running Visual Studion 2010 (Net 4.0)
I'm creating a task that loads some values into an ObservableCollection and comes back to the UI after that. This is the code:

```
LoadValues = Task.Factory.StartNew<ObservableCollection<DataGridEntity>>(curDataLoader.LoadValuesTask);
ItemsList = LoadValues.Result;
this.DataContext = ItemsList;
```

This code snippet works fine! But with the .Result Property the UI-thread waits until the LoadValues task comes back.
So I want to do it that way:

```
LoadValues = Task.Factory.StartNew<ObservableCollection<DataGridEntity>>(curDataLoader.LoadValuesTask);
LoadValues.ContinueWith((FinishLoadDataToDataGrid1) =>
{
   ItemsList = LoadValues.Result;
   this.DataContext = ItemsList;
});
```

Very little difference. I used ContinueWith to prevent the UI thread from waiting.
But if I do it that way he tells me: "Calling thread cannot access object because different thread owns it" at "this.DataContext = ItemsList;"

Is it a timing problem? Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext() to run the ContinueWith on the UI thread.

```
LoadValues = Task.Factory.StartNew<ObservableCollection<DataGridEntity>>(curDataLoader.LoadValuesTask);
LoadValues.ContinueWith((FinishLoadDataToDataGrid1) =>
{
   ItemsList = LoadValues.Result;
   this.DataContext = ItemsList;
}, CancellationToken.None, TaskContinuationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

Comment: perfect! I don't know why but hat was it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Because you are working on UI thread and when you use **ContinueWith** then your UI keep executing on UI thread and new task is executing on ThreadPool thread and when new task finishes then callback function (which is passed in ContinueWith) will execute on ThreadPool thread. 
Now callback function try to access objects owned by UI thread and system throws error.

By scheduling callback function on **TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()**, you direct system to execute this function on UI thread and everything works.

This is just explanation as D.Fihnn has already answer you question.